# Body overflow-x is set to hidden by Semantic UI - is it safe to override this?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I am using "Semantic UI" as my CSS Framework in my App' and I see that on including it in the application, `<body>` tag gets an `overflow-x:hidden` value.

I have two questions :

- Is it ok for a framework to add such a restriction on body element?
- Is it safe to override this value in my App'?

[image]

Comment: I personally can't stand when frameworks try to do too much and override global tags like that. All that's happening is that it will disallow the body from scrolling horizontally if any of your content overflows the bounds. It's probably safe to override this.

Comment: @plumwd the problem is that this hack of theirs will probably break some of their own styling when used in the app when overriden by me

Comment: Just ran into this with tables not scrolling horizontally. You should be able to override it with `body { overflow-x: inherit; }`